# how to do multithreading in cortexm3 fpga processor by using spi protocol

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, embedded, rtos

I am programming a smartfusion cortex M3 FPGA processor using SPI protocol for ethernet communication.

I want to communicate with pc over a socket(socket programming). so that server needs to handle two connections at a time i.e receiving and sending. Clearly, I want multithreading (receiving and sending data  at a time by using two parallel threads). I tried with implementing hello world example using threads. However, I am unable to get the output. I request you to help me to come out of this problem.

**NOTE -** only using multithreads I need to get output only by using two parallel threads at a time  so that it generates sending and receiving mean sending in one thread and receiving in one thread.

I tried with single thread and am getting proper output. Please suggest me the steps to perform multithreading from the below code.

Thank you in advance.

---

**single thread code:**

```
#include "uip.h"
#include "psock.h"
#include"hello_world.h"
#include"pt.h"
#include "mss_gpio.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include "./drivers/mss_spi/mss_spi.h"
#define INPUT_REG_BASE 0x40050000
#define OUTPUT_REG_BASE 0x40050000
#define OUTPUT_REG_BASE2 0x40050000
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define STATE_OUTPUT  1
#define STATE_INPUT   0
#define ISO_E     0x45
const uint32_t master_tx_frame = 0xAA;
uint32_t* INPUT_IN = (uint32_t*)INPUT_REG_BASE;
uint32_t* OUTPUT_OUT = (uint32_t*)OUTPUT_REG_BASE;
uint32_t* OUTPUT_OUT2 = (uint32_t*)OUTPUT_REG_BASE2;


static void handle_connection(struct hello_world_state *s);
static
PT_THREAD(handle_input(struct hello_world_state *s)); // handling input section thread
static
PT_THREAD(handle_output(struct hello_world_state *s)); //output section


unsigned char temp = 0;
unsigned char str[128];
int size = 128;


void hello_world_init(void)
{
uip_listen(HTONS(4002));
}


void hello_world_appcall(void)
{
struct hello_world_state *s=(struct hello_world_state *)&(uip_conn->appstate);
if(uip_connected())
{
PSOCK_INIT(&s->pin, s->inputbuffer,sizeof(s->inputbuffer)); //initializing the protosockets
//PSOCK_INIT(&s->pout, s->outputbuffer,sizeof(s->outputbuffer));
}
handle_connection(s);
}



static void
handle_connection(struct hello_world_state *s) //calling function
{
    if(s->state == STATE_INPUT)
    {``
     handle_input(s);
    }

}



static
PT_THREAD(handle_input(struct hello_world_state *s)) //input function
      {
      PSOCK_BEGIN(&s->pin);
      //PSOCK_SEND_STR(&s->p, "Hi.what is there name?\n");
      //PSOCK_READTO(&s->p, '\n');
      PSOCK_READBUF (&s->pin);

      //PSOCK_SEND_STR(&s->pin, "HI");
      PSOCK_SEND(&s->pin, s->inputbuffer,sizeof(s->inputbuffer));
     if(s->inputbuffer[0] == 0xAC)
     {

         MSS_SPI_set_slave_select(&g_mss_spi0, MSS_SPI_SLAVE_0); //spi interfacing by using threads
         MSS_SPI_transfer_frame(&g_mss_spi0, s->inputbuffer[4]);
         MSS_SPI_clear_slave_select(&g_mss_spi0, MSS_SPI_SLAVE_0);

         MSS_SPI_set_slave_select(&g_mss_spi1, MSS_SPI_SLAVE_0);
         MSS_SPI_transfer_frame(&g_mss_spi1, s->inputbuffer[4]);
         MSS_SPI_clear_slave_select(&g_mss_spi1, MSS_SPI_SLAVE_0);

     }

      else{
      PSOCK_CLOSE(&s->pin);
      PSOCK_END(&s->pin);
      }


      }

       static  PT_THREAD(handle_output(struct hello_world_state *s)) //output thread function
          {

PSOCK_BEGIN(&s->pout);
PSOCK_SEND_STR(&s->pout,"HIIIIII");
PSOCK_CLOSE(&s->pout);
PSOCK_END(&s->pout);
          }
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. You should try to clean it up and reduce it and provide a SSCCE ( http://sscce.org/ ).

Comment: Why would you need multi-threading if the ethernet connection is done by some chip with SPI? SPI always sends and receives at the same time, no threads needed. Your solution seems needlessly bloated.

Comment: You probably do not want multithreading.  At least at the lowest level, you need to maintain a consistency of state in the code managing the SPI device.  Potentially that could interact with distinct higher level threads, but you may find it easier to just implement a polling or state based mechanism.

Comment: thank u so much for providing info....sir is it possible to do sending and receiving in two separate parallel  threads...if so please help me what are the things i need to add to the above code @ chris stratton # @ ludin